# How to independently iterate each elements of python list in parralel

Tags: python

```
circle_elem = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
```

I want to simultaneously cycle/rotate each element of the above list in place
somthing like:

```
circle_elem = ['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
circle_elem = ['cdeab', 'hijfg', 'mnokl', 'rstpq', 'wxyuv']
#etc...........
```

The length of each elements in my list will always be the same

I TRIED:

```
new_cycled_list = circular_shifts(circle_elem)  
print(new_cycled_list)          ##but its rotating the entire list

        # and
for i in cycle(circle_elem):    #but its rotating the entire list
print(i)

for ii in itertools.product(circle_elem):   #this doesnt iterate all elemens separately
print(ii)
```

Any better ways to achieve the above is highly welcome.

Comment: Have you tried a list comprehension to cycle each element individually?  `new_cycled_list = [(circular_shifts(elem) for elem in circle_elem]`  (Note, this builds a new list, which or may not be what you want)

Comment: If your code works, but you're seeking advice on improvement, you may wish to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need a list comprehension that shifts each string individually.

```
>>> def circular_shifts(elems, step=1):
...     return [e[step%len(e):] + e[:step%len(e)] for e in elems]
...
>>> circle_elem = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(circular_shifts(circle_elem, i))
...
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
['cdeab', 'hijfg', 'mnokl', 'rstpq', 'wxyuv']
['deabc', 'ijfgh', 'noklm', 'stpqr', 'xyuvw']
['eabcd', 'jfghi', 'oklmn', 'tpqrs', 'yuvwx']
```

If you want to mutate the original list:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     circle_elem[:] = circular_shifts(circle_elem)
...     print(circle_elem)
...
['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
['cdeab', 'hijfg', 'mnokl', 'rstpq', 'wxyuv']
['deabc', 'ijfgh', 'noklm', 'stpqr', 'xyuvw']
['eabcd', 'jfghi', 'oklmn', 'tpqrs', 'yuvwx']
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
```

Comment: is there a way i can apply the concept of time.sleep to each element so i can determine their speed of iteration? i.e while lane1/element[0] is moving fast, lane2 is slower and so on.

Comment: That question doesn't make sense in this context, sorry.  There is no "speed" here.  You might need to back up a few steps and post a question that relates to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension with string element access will solve this for you:

```
circle_elem = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
first_cycle = [y[1:]+y[0] for y in circle_elem]
```

This returns what you're looking for:

```
['bcdea', 'ghijf', 'lmnok', 'qrstp', 'vwxyu']
```

Comment: Leave off the `5` in the slice so the code isn't inherently locked to the specific number of characters.

Comment: Smart, I'll edit to show this.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way in my opinion is create a Class:

```
>>> class Cycler():
...     def __init__(self, data):
...             self.data = data
...     def __str__(self):
...             return self.data
...     def rshift(self):
...             if self.data:
...                     self.data = self.data[-1] + self.data[:-1]
...     def lshift(self):
...             if self.data:
...                     self.data = self.data[1:] + self.data[0]
```

Like this you can shift whichever element you want and all together too

```
l = ['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy']
l = [Cycler(e) for e in l]
for e in l:
   e.rshift()
```